# App product designers, how do you track user flows?

Tags: collaboration

Hi I'm a product designer for a single page app. I would love to hear how others document/share screen flows w/ developers and product owners.

How do you illustrate navigation from one screen to the next? Are they written and posted in a PM system like JIRA, or designed and linked in Invision? This is a headache for apps with non-linear flows. I've been doing flows w/ Omnigraffle and Sketch, but they aren't the most collaborative tools (hard to version history and difficult to share).

Answer (score 1):

Any wireframing tool that allows connectors is fine. I use either Visio or Axure depending upon the complexity of the presentation. Visio is still the standard as far as I'm concerned. The following example was done in Axure.

[image]

You can add visuals (swipe or click) to inform business and developers how the app users will interact with app.

JIRA is fine as a repository to allow the various teams to view the final document but I don't think it's necessary to use JIRA to collaborate on the creation of User Flow document. (If that is what you're asking).

If UX is part of the JIRA process then of course the request to create the User Flow should be in JIRA.  This will allow tracking of questions from business and developers regarding the document and will give good feedback to the UX team regarding what the other teams need.